# Sports scores XML: if away, echo "at"; if home, echo "vs"

Tags: php, xml, if-statement

I'm using PHP to output our XML sports scores, in this example men's basketball. The page currently displays our opponents' names followed by the score and date. There are also XML attributes for home team and away team (for example, Oregon State at Stanford is: hc="stan" vc="orst").

My question is, instead of displaying only the opponents' name, i.e. "Oregon State", is it possible to display "vs Oregon State" if Oregon State is the away team OR display "at Oregon State" if Oregon State is the home team.

Here is my [page](http://bit.ly/j8CwSq), [XML](http://bit.ly/kfowoN) and code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml');

// Reverse chronological order
$xmlArray = array();
foreach ($xml as $event_date) $xmlArray[] = $event_date;
$xmlArray = array_reverse($xmlArray);

foreach ($xmlArray as $event_date)
{
    // Only output if complete
    if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
    {
    // Only show opponents' name
    $name = ($event_date->event['vc'] == 'stan') ? $event_date->event['hn'] : $event_date->event['vn'];
    echo '<li>';
        echo '<h3>', $name, '</h3>';
        echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' ', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hn'], ' ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
        echo '<p>', date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date['date'])), '</p>';
    echo '</li>';
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: can you give some sample  of an XML schedle/results?  it might be possible to infer from that PP, but itd be easier to just see the XML you describe

Comment: @jon_darkstar there's a link to the XML in my question (right above  code). Thank you.

Comment: Something that you may have to address in the future: your question asks only about home and away games as those are the only ones in the linked XML, but there is a count for neutral-site games. If those are marked in the XML in the future or in other sports' files, you'll need three conditions: home, away, and neutral.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's an excellent point. After reading your comment I checked our football XML, http://bit.ly/k8ByxV, and our Orange Bowl (neutral field) game has the same attributes as our other games: hc="vtec" vc="stan". Any idea how I'd change the output of neutral field games, i.e. from "at Virginia Tech" to "vs Virginia Tech"? I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$preposition = ($event_date->event['vc'] == 'stan') ? 'vs' : 'at';

and then use `$preposition` before the team name.

Comment: Awesome! It was backwards so I just changed *['vc']* to *['hc']* and it works perfectly. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
if($name == $event_date->event['vs']) {
   // vs
} else {
   // at
}
```

or

```
if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
{
// Only show opponents' name
$name = ($event_date->event['vc'] == 'stan') ? $event_date->event['hn'] : $event_date->event['vn'];

$playing_location = 'at'; // default
if($name == $event_date->event['vs']) {
   $playing_location = 'vs';
} 

echo '<li>';
    echo '<h3>', $name, '</h3>';
    echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' ', $event_date->event['vs'], $playing_location, $event_date->event['hn'], ' ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
    echo '<p>', date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date['date'])), '</p>';
echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Pafford - thanks for your reply. The first option output "at" for everything, while the second option changes the scores line. Sorry if I was unclear, I want to change the h3, i.e. "Oregon State" to "vs Oregon State".